# MUI (JoyUI) Autocomplete with react-hook-form : return a different value than the label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, react-hook-form

I'm working on a form with JoyUI (material) autocomplete and react-hook-form.
I have this array of object for my options :

```js
[
    { label: "Todo", param: "TODO" },
    { label: "In Progress", param: "IN_PROGRESS" },
    { label: "Ended", param: "ENDED" },
]
```

Param is the value I want to return to the API and the label the value I want to display on my autocomplete

Is it possible to display the label but return a different value to the react-hook-form (param).

Like an HTML option select (example) :

```js
<select>
    {list.map(item => (<option key={item.param} value={item.param}>{item.label}</option>))}
</select>
```

My Input component :

````js
export const Input = ({label,type,param,validation,list,register}) => (
<FormControl>
    <FormLabel>
        {label}
    </FormLabel>
    <Autocomplete
          options={list}
          {...register(param, validation)} // react-hook-form register
      />

</FormControl>);```

Thanks,
````

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getOptionLabel`

```js
 export const Input = ({label,type,param,validation,list,register}) => (
<FormControl>
    <FormLabel>
        {label}
    </FormLabel>
    <Autocomplete
          options={list}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label} // this will show label in the dropdown
          {...register(param, validation)} // react-hook-form register
      />

</FormControl>);
```